# Android Studio Room db data not available when emulator is changed

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-room

I was my assignment code on different emulator devices and I noticed that if I change emulator devices, the data I added to my Room db no longer exist. If I go back to the original emulator I used to insert the data, the data appears. How do I make the data be available using on multiple emulator devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem could be that one of the devices is not API 26+.

Another problem could be that the App is not running in which case if you try to swap you you get **No Debuggable process detected** e.g.:

[image]

If both are running are you swapping to the other? e.g.

[image]

And then when swapped :-

[image]

*(note the different created_at values between the first screen shot on the API 28 device and the last screen shot on the API 29 device)*